# Flutter implement overlay in center between two widgets

Tags: flutter, user-interface, mobile, widget, stack

I want to add extended app bar with pattern for background. Below this fill screen with scrollable content. And above both views in center i want to show "header content".

**My current view**

[image]

1. Currently i'm using CompositedTransformTarget and showing overlay. The problem which i have is that i have to hide/show overlay when navigation to next screen and then back. Is there any event for pause/resume widget?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
        canPop: true,
        onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
          _removeHeaderInfoOverlay();
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          body:
              Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                      blurRadius: 7,
                      offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                    ),
                  ],
                  color: Color(0xff00B9FF),
                  image: const DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/app_bar_pattern.png'),
                  )),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  _appBarView(context),
                  CompositedTransformTarget(
                    link: _layerLink,
                    child: SizedBox(height: shopOverviewHeight / 2),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    child: _prepareShopItem(widget.data)))
          ]),
        ));
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      _insertHeaderItem();
    });
  }
```

2. I could use stack and add fix padding from top. Are appBars the same height on all devices (IOS,Android) in flutter ?
3. Between my appBar and SingleChildScrollView when scrolling appBar shadow is below items.

I have try all i could find